# xml - xpath select third node after a certain node

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an xml file which looks like this:

```
<item id="1991901" >
    <property name="image">
        <property>
            <property name="image_realtyimagetype_id">
                <value>pääkuva</value>
            </property>
            <property name="image_itemimagetype_name">
               <value>kivirealty-original</value>
            </property>
            <property name="image_desc">
               <value></value>
            </property>
            <property name="image_url">
               <value>http://domain.com/img4092288730864152376.jpg</value>
            </property>

[...]
```

It contains a lot of items with different pictures and other data.

Is there a direct way to get the value of "image_url" in the case, where value "image_realtyimagetype_id" is "pääkuva" without going through the whole tree with foreachs? (there is only one "pääkuva" in every item-id)

The "image_realtyimagetype_id" can also state "yleiskuva" or similar, but I need only the "pääkuva" (which means main image)

I got until now only the first of the images in the file like this:

```
$path = '//item[@id="'.$itemId.'"]/property[@name="image"]/property/property[@name="image_url"]/value/text()';
```

But now I need the certain image. Is there a way to do this directly with xpath?

Comment: So you want the value of property name ="image_url" where its sibling image_realtyimagetype_id has value equal to "pääkuva"?
Or does the existence of image_url automatically mean it's the main image?

Comment: no, there are about 30 images with an "image_url" but only one has the image_realtyimagetype_id equal "pääkuva".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long XPath:

<del>http://3v4l.org/HtUUD

`//item/property[@name="image"]/property[//property[@name="image_realtyimagetype_id"]/value/text()="pääkuva"]/property[@name="image_url"]/value/text()`</del>

http://3v4l.org/4VpU3

`//item/property[@name="image"]/property[property[@name="image_realtyimagetype_id"]/value/text()="pääkuva"]/property[@name="image_url"]/value/text()`

Thanks @dirkk

Comment: No I am sorry its not working. I tested the eval when there are several images, it retrieves all images, despite if its a "pääkuva" or not

http://3v4l.org/ZWBP3

Comment: `//property` in the condition should be `property`. Also, instead of `value/text()` you can simply compare to `value`

Comment: thank you @silkfire solution from passerby works already, but I am sure yours is helpful to some other too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
//item[@id="1991901"]//property[@name="image_realtyimagetype_id"]/value[text() = "pääkuva"]/../following-sibling::property[@name="image_url"]/value
```